# Android: Growing backstack problem, how to conserve memory?

Tags: android

our app is designed using fragments and fragment transactions in a way where the user can keep going forward and "grow" our backstack indefinately.  Now, besides the "dont design the app that way" answer, what options do I have to conserve memory.  Eventually we run out and crash.  Is there a way to onSaveInstanceState, save most of the state, release all the views (which hopefully releases memory associated with them), and then reload the views?  Or is there a way to remove some transactions from the bottom of the stack?  We are ok with loosing some of the user's backstack history if it comes from the bottom of the stack.  Meaning: we would only keep the last 5 transactions in memory or something like that.

Comment: How many before you run out of memory and crash? Are you sure it's an out of memory issue? This should be in the thousands if not tens of thousands unless you have memory leaks or HUGE extras in the arguments for the fragment.

Comment: Well, its very different per device.  But we can only get to 30 or so on some devices.  We also have ALOT of bitmaps on each screen so that might be part of the problem.  We have done our best to track the leaks and perhaps a leak is the problem.  However, if you go into a transaction then back out of it, and do this multiple times, we dont really run out of memory.  Its more if the backstack just keeps growing that we run out.